# All possible combinations of values in python

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations, python-itertools

Version: **Python 3.4.3**

Hi, I'm trying to create an script that reads the availible options from some select items in an html file and creates a database with all the possible choices assigning them an unique ID based on their values.

This is the structure of the html:

```
              <select id="perforar" onchange="Actualiza(this.id, this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
              <option value="g1">sin perforacion</option>
              <option value="g2">1 Linea de perforación</option>
              <option value="g3">2 Lineas de perforación</option>
              <option value="g4">3 Lineas de perforación</option>
              <option value="g5">4 Lineas de perforación</option>
              <option value="g6">5 Lineas de perforación</option>
              <option value="g7">6 Lineas de perforación</option>
            </select></td>
            </tr><tr><td>Ennoblecimiento: </td><td>
            <select id="ennoblecimiento" onchange="Actualiza(this.id, this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
              <option value="h1">sin ennoblecimiento</option>
              <option value="h2">barniz UV</option>
              <option value="h3">laminado</option>
            </select></td>
            </tr><tr><td>Plegado: </td><td>
            <select id="plegado" onchange="Actualiza(this.id, this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
              <option value="i1">plegado envolvente</option>
              <option value="i2">plegado en acordéon</option>
              <option value="i3">plegado en ventana</option>
```

I manually copy/paste all that into a .txt and then run this code:

```
#load file into buffer
leyendo = open("generadorbasedatos.txt", 'r')
archivotxt = leyendo.read()
leyendo.close()
#split it for lines
listadividida = []
listadividida= archivotxt.split("\n")
#create a dict for later
basededatos = {}

#for each line
for i in listadividida:
    if not "<option" in i: #if isn't an option, delete that line
        i = ""
    else: #if it's an option, get the value and the text
        #the text
        desde = '>'
        hasta = '<'
        _,_,resto = i.partition(desde)
        opcion,_,_ = resto.partition(hasta)
        #the value
        desde = 'value="'
        hasta = '">'
        _,_,resto = i.partition(desde)
        laid,_,_ = resto.partition(hasta)
        #add them to a dict
        basededatos[laid] = [opcion, laid]
        #And this is where I'm lost and I need help
print(basededatos)
```

Now comes the trouble, I want the script to create a list of all possible combinations and assign an ID for each combination using the values to create the ID, so the output should look like this:

```
g1h1i1: [1 Linea de perforación, Sin ennoblecimiento, plegado envolvente]
g1h1i2: [1 Linea de perforación, Sin ennoblecimiento, plegado en acordeón]
g1h1i3: [1 Linea de perforación, Sin ennoblecimiento, plegado en ventana]
g1h2i1: [1 Linea de perforación, barniz, plegado envolvente]
g1h2i2: [1 Linea de perforación, barniz, plegado plegado en acordeón]
g1h3i3: [1 Linea de perforación, barniz, plegado en ventana]
```

And eventually all possible combinations. I tried with itertools and somehow managed to freeze my computer (probably due to out of memory or endless loops issues) so now I'm asking here.

**What's the best way to achieve what I want to do?**

Notice: There is more than 12 selects, only copy/pasted 3 of them here as example, but the code should be able to create all combinations of more than just 3 selects.

Comment: Do you need the `[1 Linea de perforación, Sin ennoblecimiento, plegado envolvente]` part or is it enough to create the "unique IDs" with a list of which options that encompasses.

Comment: If there are more than 12 selects, you'll get a huge number of combinations - assuming 5 items per select on average means over 240 million combinations (`5**12`). That's probably why it takes a little while...

Comment: @pzp Ideally I'd want to know what options actually create that unique ID.

Comment: @TimPietzcker uhm, I didn't though it would be more than 500... oh god, did I waste 10 hours? Honestly what I want to do is more or less like this form: http://www.saxoprint.es/shop/flyers in order to update the price accordingly to the choices. I have no idea how it's programmed so I was trying to replicate it somehow.

Comment: rather that save every posible combination, they are a lot, save the characteristic of each one and when given a certain combination calculate the value of that combination from the value of each one, price in this case, and have a default value that is neutral to the calculus (0 if adding, 1 if multiplication, etc ) if needed for any missing item. And when a new item is selected or unselected recalculate the whole thing. That is more or less how that form you want to replicate is made

Answer (score 0):

From your point, this achieve you goal :

```
from itertools import product
base={'g':[],'h':[],'i':[]}
for (key,value) in basededatos.items(): base[key[0]].append(value) # to split the fields.
products=product(*base.values()) #make all combinations
finaldict={ "".join([p[1] for p in t]) : [p[0] for p in t] for t in products }
# formatting in a dictionnary.
```

Some values :

```
In [263]: base
Out[263]: 
{'g': [['1 Linea de perforación', 'g2'],
  ['4 Lineas de perforación', 'g5'],
  ['2 Lineas de perforación', 'g3'],
  ....,
 'h': [['laminado', 'h3'], ['barniz UV', 'h2'], ['sin ennoblecimiento', 'h1']],
 'i': [['plegado en ventana', 'i3'],
  ['plegado en acordéon', 'i2'],
  ....]}


In [265]: finaldict
Out[265]: 
{'g1h3i2': ['sin perforacion', 'laminado', 'plegado en acordéon'],
'g7h2i1': ['6 Lineas de perforación', 'barniz UV', 'plegado envolvente'],
'g2h3i3': ['1 Linea de perforación', 'laminado', 'plegado en ventana'],....
```

Comment: This finaldict line doesn't works for me when I add 11 values to base instead of just 3 (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k). Could be because there's too much combinations?

Comment: Probably. There is (number of choices for a)*(number of choices for b)*...*(number of choices for k) combinations. How many ?